# How to give one role to multiple discord user using the user id

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to give one role named helper to multiple users whose user id's are in a list called user_id

Here is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def role(ctx):
   user_id = ['752535843490616142' , '852495843390536197', '752595643220636947']
   role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name = "Helpers")   
   for member in user_id:
       await member.add_roles(role)
       await ctx.send('roles have been given')
```

This is the error I got:

```
Ignoring exception in command role:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\upaay\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python projects\Discord Bots\MC Server bot\Local\untitled0.py", line 22, in role
    await member.add_roles(role)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'add_roles'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\upaay\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\upaay\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\upaay\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'add_roles'
```

Comment: You are looping over the user_id's which are strings, not discord member objects. So what you are attempting to do with your code is '752535843490616142'.add_role(role). In the for loop, you could get the member object by their user_id and then add the role to the member object.

Comment: *PS: IDs are integers, not strings*

Comment: Okay, so you have a list of user IDs, and you want to get the corresponding *user* so that you can do something with it. What does the documentation say about how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started by renaming some of the variables for clarity. I then got the member object using the user_ids and then added the role. Finally, I moved the `await ctx.send('roles have been given')` outside of the for loop so that it'll only send a single message.

```
@client.command()
async def role(ctx):
    user_ids = [752535843490616142, 852495843390536197, 752595643220636947]
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Helpers")
    for user_id in user_ids:
       member = ctx.guild.get_member(user_id)
       await member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send('roles have been given')
```